# Unreal: "Unknown type name UTextRenderComponent" compile error while following tutorial

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Tutorials/VariablesTimersEvents/1/index.html) and I literally copied and pasted the content of Countdown.h and Countdown.cpp.

Visual Studio Code (I'm on mac) gives the following hint

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
cannot open source file "new" (dependency of "GameFramework/Actor.h")
```

at this line

```
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
```

while the compilation error I get from UE is the following

```
Running Mono...

Setting up Mono
~/Documents/UE_4.18/Engine ~/Documents/UE_4.18/Engine/Binaries/Mac
Compiling game modules for hot reload
Parsing headers for HowTo_VTEEditor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/HowTo_VTE.uproject" "/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/HowTo_VTEEditor/Development/HowTo_VTEEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Reflection code generated for HowTo_VTEEditor in 10,277899 seconds
Performing 3 actions (5 in parallel)
[2/3] Compile Countdown.cpp
[1/3] Compile Countdown.gen.cpp
In file included from /Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.gen.cpp:8:
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h:29:5: error: unknown type name 'UTextRenderComponent'
    UTextRenderComponent* CountdownText;
    ^
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h:12:5: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'UObject *' with an rvalue of type 'ACountdown *'
    GENERATED_BODY()
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:585:29: note: expanded from macro 'GENERATED_BODY'
#define GENERATED_BODY(...) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(CURRENT_FILE_ID,_,__LINE__,_GENERATED_BODY);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:580:37: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE'
#define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(A,B,C,D) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:579:43: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER'
#define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D) A##B##C##D
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.generated.h:81:2: note: expanded from macro 'HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_GENERATED_BODY'
        HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.generated.h:57:54: note: expanded from macro 'HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS'
        DECLARE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR(NO_API, ACountdown); \
                                                            ^
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:1387:11: note: expanded from macro '\
DEFINE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR_CALLER'
                        return new (EC_InternalUseOnlyConstructor, (UObject*)GetTransientPackage(), NAME_None, RF_NeedLoad | RF_ClassDefaultObject | RF_TagGarbageTemp) TClass(Helper); \
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:1:
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h:29:5: error: unknown type name 'UTextRenderComponent'
    UTextRenderComponent* CountdownText;
    ^
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h:12:5: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'UObject *' with an rvalue of type 'ACountdown *'
    GENERATED_BODY()
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:585:29: note: expanded from macro 'GENERATED_BODY'
#define GENERATED_BODY(...) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(CURRENT_FILE_ID,_,__LINE__,_GENERATED_BODY);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:580:37: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE'
#define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE(A,B,C,D) BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:579:43: note: expanded from macro 'BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER'
#define BODY_MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B,C,D) A##B##C##D
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 1 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.generated.h:81:2: note: expanded from macro 'HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_GENERATED_BODY'
        HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.generated.h:57:54: note: expanded from macro 'HowTo_VTE_Source_HowTo_VTE_Countdown_h_12_ENHANCED_CONSTRUCTORS'
        DECLARE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR(NO_API, ACountdown); \
                                                            ^
Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h:1387:11: note: expanded from macro '\
DEFINE_VTABLE_PTR_HELPER_CTOR_CALLER'
                        return new (EC_InternalUseOnlyConstructor, (UObject*)GetTransientPackage(), NAME_None, RF_NeedLoad | RF_ClassDefaultObject | RF_TagGarbageTemp) TClass(Helper); \
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:11:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UTextRenderComponent'
    CountdownText = CreateDefaultSubobject<UTextRenderComponent>(TEXT("CountdownNumber"));
                                           ^
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:12:43: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EHTA_Center'; did you mean 'kTXNCenter'?
    CountdownText->SetHorizontalAlignment(EHTA_Center);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                          kTXNCenter
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/MacTextEditor.h:793:3: note: 'kTXNCenter' declared here
  kTXNCenter                    = 4,
  ^
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:22:12: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'AActor' with an expression of type 'ACountdown'
    Super::BeginPlay();
           ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:25:5: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const AActor' with an expression of type 'ACountdown'
    GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(CountdownTimerHandle, this, &ACountdown::AdvanceTimer, 1.0f, true);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:31:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'Tick'
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );
    ~~~~~~~^~~~
Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/Actor.h:2077:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'ACountdown' to 'AActor' for object argument
        virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds );
                     ^
Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/Actor.h:2432:15: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        virtual void Tick( float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType ) final
                     ^
/Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.cpp:47:9: error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const AActor' with an expression of type 'ACountdown'
        GetWorldTimerManager().ClearTimer(CountdownTimerHandle);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
8 errors generated.
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Binaries/Mac/UE4Editor-HowTo_VTE-6063.dylib
Total build time: 28,61 seconds (Local executor: 0,00 seconds)
```

It's as if the two errors are related, but I don't get what could be wrong.
I noticed that while my project is situated in `/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowToVTE/Countdown.cpp`
the Unreal stuff is in `Documents/UE_4.18/Engine/...`
could this be the culprit for which the include is not found?

edit: i tried the include with the absolute path to Actor.h but i get the same compile error

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to understand what this error was telling you:

```
[1/3] Compile Countdown.gen.cpp
In file included from /Users/massimobortolamei/Documents/Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Inc/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.gen.cpp:8:
../../../Unreal Projects/HowTo_VTE/Source/HowTo_VTE/Countdown.h:29:5: error: unknown type name 'UTextRenderComponent'
    UTextRenderComponent* CountdownText;
    ^
```

Your compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what a UTextRenderComponent is because the file that defines it hasn't yet been included. This is why adding the include (`#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/TextRenderComponent.h"`) worked. It's not, however, generally a good idea to include other headers in your existing headers, as this will bloat your compile times on large projects ([Here's](https://blog.knatten.org/2012/11/09/another-reason-to-avoid-includes-in-headers/) a decent explanation of why this is.)

A better practice is to forward-declare the UTextRenderComponent in your header, and then include the TextRenderComponent header in your .cpp file. ([Some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) about forward declarations) Unreal's build tool provides a convenient way to do this using the class keyword.

Declare your member variable like this:

```
class UTextRenderComponent* CountdownText;
```

And then include the required header in your .cpp file.
What you're doing in this instance is telling your compiler that UTextRenderComponent is a class, and you're promising to supply the definition later on. Your compiler doesn't need to know what that definition is while it's parsing Countdown.h because you're just including a pointer to the class, so it doesn't need to know its size or anything else about it - just that it's a class defined somewhere else.

So yes, the solution you found above will work but is less ideal than forward-declaring your class in your header and then including other headers in your implementation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your insight. I read the link provided about why compile time is affected by declaring headers in other headers, and i also read the first comment which stated that not always it is a good idea because it really depends. In this specific case Countdown.h is only used by Countdown.cpp, wouldn't it be the same to declare the missing TextRenderComponent.h either in Countdown.h or in Countdown.cpp?

Comment: In this instance, yes, you'd probably be fine including the header in your Countdown header since the header isn't included elsewhere. Sometimes including another header in a header is unavoidable as well, if you're using a user-defined class or struct in the header. In general, though, it's good to get in the habit of using forward declarations in favor of including headers in headers when you can, as it will make a difference on a larger project. Your instinct is correct though - whether this guideline makes sense in a specific situation depends.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question on the Answerhub of Unreal, and a kind user was able to provide a solution.

You can see it [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/730971/unknown-type-name-utextrendercomponent-while-follo.html)

For short: add `#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/TextRenderComponent.h"` to the includes in `Countdown.h` (Leaving the autogenerated include as last, of course)